# How to create a localized time ago String on Android

Tags: android, localization

I was reviewing the [Google I/O Session 2012 app](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/util/TimeUtils.java) and came across this TODO

```
public static String getTimeAgo(long time, Context ctx) {
    if (time < 1000000000000L) {
        // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
        time *= 1000;
    }

    long now = getCurrentTime(ctx);
    if (time > now || time <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // TODO: localize
    final long diff = now - time;
    if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "just now";
    } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "a minute ago";
    } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " minutes ago";
    } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "an hour ago";
    } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours ago";
    } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return "yesterday";
    } else {
        return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";
    }
}
```

Which made me wonder what would be the steps to localizing it.

Comment: The sources have moved to https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/util/TimeUtils.java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Ian Lake's answer:

```
final CharSequence relativeTimeSpan = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, 0);
```

[DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29) produces things such as the following:

- 42 minutes ago
- 10 seconds ago
- in 1 hour

Alternatively, this would allow translations to be provided through the Android `res` framework using the given `Context`, useful if your desired messaging difference from what you can get out of the framework method.

```
public static String getTimeAgo(long time, Context context) {
    if (time < 1000000000000L)
        // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
        time *= 1000;

    final long now = getCurrentTime(context);
    if (time > now || time <= 0) return "";


    final Resources res = context.getResources();
    final long time_difference = now - time;
    if (time_difference < _A_MINUTE)
        return res.getString(R.string.just_now);
    else if (time_difference < 50 * _A_MINUTE)
        return res.getString(R.string.time_ago,
                             res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.minutes, (int) time_difference / _A_MINUTE, time_difference / _A_MINUTE));
    else if (time_difference < 24 * _AN_HOUR)
        return res.getString(R.string.time_ago,
                             res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.hours, (int) time_difference / _AN_HOUR, time_difference / _AN_HOUR));
    else if (time_difference < 48 * _AN_HOUR)
        return res.getString(R.string.yesterday);
    else
        return res.getString(R.string.time_ago,
                             res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.days, (int) time_difference / _A_DAY, time_difference / _A_DAY));
}
```

where I defined the constants as:

```
/** One second (in milliseconds) */
private static final int _A_SECOND = 1000;
/** One minute (in milliseconds) */
private static final int _A_MINUTE = 60 * _A_SECOND;
/** One hour (in milliseconds) */
private static final int _AN_HOUR = 60 * _A_MINUTE;
/** One day (in milliseconds) */
private static final int _A_DAY = 24 * _AN_HOUR;
```

Then the rest of the work is in the structure of the plurals and string resources.

My default local is en, so `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<!-- time ago strings -->
<string name="just_now">just now</string>
<string name="time_ago">%s ago</string>
<string name="yesterday">yesterday</string>
```

Then `res/values/plurals.xml`:

```
<plurals name="minutes">
    <item quantity="one">a minute</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d minutes</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="hours">
    <item quantity="one">an hour</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d hours</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="days">
    <item quantity="one">a day</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d days</item>
</plurals>
```

This approach should allow you to localize on the vocabulary and the grammar of the language, as different languages not only have different words for words like "minute", but they also have different rules about how to pluralize words based on the quantity. So the plurals resource utilizes the Android frameworks support of localizing on pluralizations. All that is left is to provide the translations.

Comment: I am not getting values .. just % minutes ago!! What should i do?

Comment: I am also gettting  % minutes

Comment: sorry, it's a common mistake to forget to include the quantity twice. Once for the plurals logic and once for the string format. @andrewww

Comment: Hello @DandreAllison. Thank you for this function! I observed a slight error in calculating the hour (it displays 0 hour ago). It is caused by the division operation of long and int, and when you cast to int, you can get 0 value. I fixed it by using Math.ceil and some casting. Please see my addition on this question.

Answer (score 21):

If you don't need custom strings, you can also use [DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29), which produces strings such as:

- 42 minutes ago
- 10 seconds ago
- in 1 hour

Sample usage:

```
final CharSequence relativeTimeSpan = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, 0);
```

Comment: Nice, that's good to know. I was just going off of the implementation in the I/O session app.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to Dandre's answer except:

- Yesterday is defined based on Calendar time instead of seconds.

  - For example, when:

    - Post time is *10:00:00 p.m. 01/19/2015*
    - and Current time is *01:00:00 a.m. 01/20/2015*
  - Formatted date should print: **Yesterday** instead of **3 hours ago**

First, let's write our main function that return the formatted date:

```
public String getStringFormattedDate(Context context, Date postDate){
    Calendar postCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    postCalendar.setTime(postDate);
    Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    long delta = Math.abs(currentCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - postCalendar .getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;

    //**yesterday**
    //This has to be checked first, otherwise, yesterday logic 
    //will be overridden by "seconds ago", "minutes ago", "hours ago"
    if(isYesterday(postCalendar , currentCalendar)){
        return context.getResources().getString(R.string.yesterday);
    }
    //seconds ago
    else if (delta < 60)
    {
        return context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.seconds, (int)delta, (int)delta);
    }
    //minutes ago
    else if (delta < 3600) // 60 * 60
    {
        delta /= 60.0; // convert seconds to minutes
        return context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.minutes, (int)delta, (int)delta);
    }
    //hours ago
    else if (delta < 86400) // 24 * 60 * 60
    {
        delta /= (60.0*60.0); // convert seconds to hours
        return context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.hours, (int)delta, (int)delta);
    }
    //older dates
    else{
       delta /= (60.0*60.0*24.0); // convert seconds to days
       return context.getResources().getString(R.string.time_ago, context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.days, (int) delta , (int) delta));
    }
}
```

Function `isYesterday()` that checks if postCalendar is yesterday compared to current calendar:

```
//return true, if postCalendar is a day behind currentCalendar
private boolean isYesterday(Calendar postCalendar, Calendar currentCalendar){
    Calendar cloneCurrentCalendar = (Calendar) currentCalendar.clone();
    resetTime(cloneCurrentCalendar);

    Calendar clonePostCalendar = (Calendar) postCalendar.clone();
    resetTime(clonePostCalendar);
    clonePostCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    return (cloneCurrentCalendar.compareTo(clonePostCalendar) == 0);
}
```

Function `resetTime()` that reset a calendar instance for purpose of comparing calendar dates only:

```
//set Time to 00:00:00
private void resetTime(Calendar calendar){
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly edited code in the answer. I got "0 hour ago" strings, which are caused by division of long and int. Additionally, `getCurrentTime()` method was missing in the answer so I used `System.getCurrentTimeInMillis()`. Here is my modification which solves `0 hour ago` problem.

```
public static String getTimeAgo(long time, Context context) {
    if (time < 1000000000000L) {
        // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
        time *= 1000;
    }

    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (time > now || time <= 0) return "";

    final Resources res = context.getResources();
    final long time_difference = now - time;

    if (time_difference < C._A_MINUTE)
        return res.getString(R.string.just_now);
    else if (time_difference < 50 * C._A_MINUTE)
        return res.getString(R.string.time_ago,
            res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.minutes, (int) time_difference / C._A_MINUTE, time_difference / C._A_MINUTE));
    else if (time_difference < 24 * C._AN_HOUR)
        return res.getString(R.string.time_ago,
            res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.hours, (int) Math.ceil((double)time_difference / C._AN_HOUR), time_difference / C._AN_HOUR));
    else if (time_difference < 48 * C._AN_HOUR)
        return res.getString(R.string.yesterday);
    else
        return res.getString(R.string.time_ago,
            res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.days, (int) Math.ceil((double)time_difference / C._A_DAY), time_difference / C._A_DAY));
}
```

`C.java` is where I keep my constants. Here it is:

```
public class C {
    /** One second (in milliseconds) */
    public static final int _A_SECOND = 1000;
    /** One minute (in milliseconds) */
    public static final int _A_MINUTE = 60 * _A_SECOND;
    /** One hour (in milliseconds) */
    public static final int _AN_HOUR = 60 * _A_MINUTE;
    /** One day (in milliseconds) */
    public static final int _A_DAY = 24 * _AN_HOUR;
```

Other files (`plurals.xml` and `strings.xml`) are same. Please see the answer above.