# Create a localised duration string

Tags: java, android, localization, locale

I need a string like `31 days` or `12 Hours` if the phone locale is English, or (for example) `31 Tage` etc. if the phone locale is in German.  Note: no `at`, `on`, `by` etc. prefix, nor `ago` etc. suffix.

Ideally other languages would work too, but those are the two I need.

My values are currently milliseconds, but naturally I can convert as required.

I can localise my own strings and use them, but is there a built-in way to do this?

(This question is similar to, but not answered by, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203018/how-to-create-a-localized-time-ago-string-on-android).)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test any Java code here, but have you tried `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString` while the language is set to German? Does it return something like `vor 31 Tage`?

If so, you could make sure your timespan is always in the past, so "5 hours ago", "12 days ago" etc. and never a future timespan like "in 3 days". And then in your translate strings:

```
string_ago = "ago" // en strings.xml
string_ago = "vor" // de strings.xml
```

And then in code just remove the "ago" so something like this.

```
final CharSequence relativeTimeSpan = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timepast, now, 0);

String strtimespan = relativeTimeSpan.toString();
String strago = resources.getString(R.string.string_ago); // "ago" or "vor" depending on language setting

strtimespan.replace(strago, ""); // remove "ago" or "vor"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think, though, if I'm going to have my own localised strings ("vor" etc.), I might just as well do the whole thing explicitly...